# Formatting to Currency VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

All I need is the following code to get the variable into currency mode.

```
        lines.Add("Labor Cost Per Run:" & laborCostpRun.ToString & "     Per Peice: " & laborCostpPc.ToString & "     Per Year: " & laborcostpYr.ToString)
```

I have tried using {0:C2} everywhere, to no end... I know its something simple that I am missed... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a format string to `ToString()`:

```
laborCostpRun.ToString("C2")
```

Alternatively, you could replace the entire concatenation with a `string.Format()` call with formatted placeholders (`{0:C2}`).

Comment: I'd recommend this answer as it's .NET friendly (i.e; works with other .NET languages, unlike the Format and FormatCurrency functions specific to VB).

Answer (score 1):

For me `String.Format("{0:C2}", Total)` worked. 
Total has to be a numeric object (in my case a decimal). Using this formatter on a string may give different results.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different ways you could do it:

Using the Format Function ([link to MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h(v=vs.90).aspx))

```
Format(laborCostpRun,"Currency")
```

Using ToString with a Specified Format ([link to MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
laborCostpRun.ToString("c")
```

Both methods offer too many formatting options to spell them all out here.  Check the links for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [FormatCurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function:

```
lines.Add("Labor Cost Per Run:" & FormatCurrency(laborCostpRun, 2) & "     Per Peice: " & FormatCurrency(laborCostpPc, 2) & "     Per Year: " & FormatCurrency(laborcostpYr, 2))
```